# Как реализовать фильтрацию по цвету на Woocommerce, если у товара может быть 2 и более цветов?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wp-plugin

Привет. 
У меня вопрос по фильтрации в WP на WooCommerce. Интересует фильтрация по цвету. 
Товар - натуральный камень. Например плита камня может быть черного и зеленого цвета. Или черная и желтая. 
И для дизайнеров и архитекторов важно при фильтрации выбрать микс из нескольких цветов. 
Например, если указывают черный и желтый - выходит тот что только с данными параметрами. 
Может быть посоветуете какой-нибудь плагин с Ajax?

Comment: Погуглите woocommerce filters. https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-products-filter/ https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-ajax-filters/

Comment: установил pro версию второго плагина, вполне нормально, спасибо!